# jQuery search api and no results

Tags: 2013, search, rest

I try to get search results using a javascript (jQuery) call to my on premise SharePoint search REST API but I don't get any results.

that's my js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://my.local.domain/_api/search/query",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    data: { querytext: "'ContentType:MyContentType'", rowlimit: 1, trimduplicates: false, selectproperties: "'Title%2c+LastModifiedTime'", sortlist:"'LastModifiedTime:descending'" },
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(function( json ) {
}
```

jQuery call this url:

```
http://my.local.domain/_api/search/query?querytext=%27ContentType%3AMyContentType%27&rowlimit=1&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties=%27Title%252c%2BLastModifiedTime%27&sortlist=%27LastModifiedTime%3Adescending%27
```

The url I enter manually is a bit different:

```
http://my.local.domain/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:FsgNewsContentType'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=1&selectproperties='Title%2cLastModifiedTime'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'
```

It looks as if there's a problem with the encoding of the special characters.

Comment: Type that URL in your browser and check if you are getting any results?

Comment: Are you calling your javascript code from sharepoint page only?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser?

Comment: I get an empty json or xml result but no error message

Answer (score 4):

In your example since `HTTP GET` request is used, query parameters **have to be specified in the URL**. You can construct the GET request URL in two ways:

- `http://server/_api/search/query?query_parameter=value&query_parameter=value`
- `http://server/_api/search/query(query_parameter=value&query_parameter=<value>)`

---

The Search REST service supports both `HTTP POST` and `HTTP GET` requests. The following examples demonstrate how to consume Search Query REST Interface using JavaScript.

### How to consume Search Query REST Interface using JavaScript

Assume the following query is used `contentclass:STS_ListItem AND ContentType:Task` to retrieve task items.

**Search GET request**

```
function getJson(endpointUrl,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }, 
      url: endpointUrl, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}

function searchTasks(webUrl,success, failure) {
    var searchUrl = webUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_ListItem AND ContentType:Task'";
    getJson(searchUrl,success,failure);
}
```

Usage

```
//get and print tasks
searchTasks(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
  function(data){
      var query = data.d.query; 
      var resultsCount = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
      for(var i = 0; i < resultsCount;i++) {
          var row = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i];
          var taskName = row.Cells.results[3].Value;
          console.log(taskName);
      }   
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

**Search POST request**

```
function postJson(endpointUrl,payload,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      url: endpointUrl, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}


function searchTasks(webUrl,success, failure) {
    var searchUrl = webUrl + "/_api/search/postquery";
    var searchPayload = {
      'request': {
         '__metadata' : {'type' : 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest'},
         'Querytext' : 'contentclass:STS_ListItem AND ContentType:Task'
      }  
    };     
    postJson(searchUrl,searchPayload,success,failure);
}
```

Usage

```
searchTasks(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
  function(data){
      var query = data.d.postquery; 
      var resultsCount = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
      for(var i = 0; i < resultsCount;i++) {
          var row = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i];
          var taskName = row.Cells.results[3].Value;
          console.log(taskName);
      }   
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

### References

[SharePoint Search REST API overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It work if I pass the data as string (not as object) and set processData to false.

```
data: "querytext='ContentType:MyContentType'&rowlimit=1&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,LastModifiedTime'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'",
processData: false,
```

Comment: You could find the examples how perform requests to SharePoint Search REST API in my answer.

Comment: If you pass a data object (and it is an object), you must pass it to the `$.ajax()` request as  `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: @wjervis data takes PlainObject, String or Array, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @jlai79, and yet it fails otherwise.  SharePoint expects it as a string.